# Suggestions with Strings from File

Tags: java, string, random

I am trying to read from a external file. I have successfully read from the file but now I have a little problem. The file contains around 88 verbs. The verbs are written in the file like this: 
be was been
beat beat beaten
become became become
and so on...

What I need help with now is that I want a  quiz like programe where only two random strings from the verb will come up and the user have to fill inn the one which is missing. Instead of the one missing, I want this("------"). My english is not so good so I hope you understand what I mean.

```
    System.out.println("Welcome to the programe which will test you in english verbs!");
    System.out.println("You can choose to be tested in up to 88.");
    System.out.println("In the end of the programe you will get a percentage of total right answers.");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Do you want to try??yes/no");

    String a = in.nextLine();
    if (a.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file you want to choose: ");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Programe is ended!");
    }



    String b = in.nextLine();
    while(!b.equals("verb.txt")){
        System.out.println("You entered wrong name, please try again!");
         b = in.nextLine();

    }
    System.out.println("How many verbs do you want to be tested in?: ");
    int totalVerb = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();


    String filename = "verb.txt";
    File textFile = new File(filename);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(textFile);

    for (int i = 1; i <= totalVerb; i++){



        String line = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println("Please fill inn the missing verb: ");
        in.next();
    }

    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
    in.next();
```

Comment: be more specific, what can't you do? We don't want run your code to figure it out.

Comment: Do you want to check if the verb exists in the file or something?

Comment: What I need help with now is that I want a quiz like programe where only two random strings from the verb will come up and the user have to fill inn the one which is missing. Instead of the one missing, I want this("------").

Comment: Is it like this , every line has 3 verbs(present,past,participle) and you want to show any two from these three and the user have to fill the third one.???

Comment: What do you mean `Strings from the verb"? I don't really get that.

Comment: Absolutely right Bharath Rallapalli!

Comment: Please look at what Mr Bharath Rallapalli wrote. He have understood!

Comment: How will you determine which word will be ----- ? is it random, or do you always want the middle one?

Comment: I want random my friend

Comment: And my friends, I can not understand how to program so the programe should automatically check if the answer from the user is right or wrong.. any suggestions for that as well?

Comment: Anyone who can help? Simple method please

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class GuessVerb {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a file name: ");

        String fileName = in.nextLine();
        File file = new File(fileName);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        String guess = null;
        int correctCount = 0;

        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();          // get the line

            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");    // split it into 3 word

            int randNum = (int)(Math.random() * 3);  // get a random number 0, 1, 2

            String newLine = null;                          // new line

            int wordIndex = 0;
            switch(randNum){                         // case for random number
                case 0: newLine = "------ " + tokens[1] + " " + tokens[2]; 
                            wordIndex = 0; break;
                case 1: newLine = tokens[0] + " ------ " + tokens[2]; 
                            wordIndex = 1; break;
                case 2: newLine = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1] + " -------";
                            wordIndex = 2; break;
           }

           System.out.println(newLine);

           System.out.println("Please fill inn the missing verb: ");
           guess = in.nextLine();

           if (guess.equals(tokens[wordIndex])){
               correctCount++;
           }
        }
        System.out.println("You got " + correctCount + " right");
    }
}
```

Above is complete running program.

Comment: You might be able to just replace your `for` loop with it. The `while` loop runs through the entire file, line by line. When there are no more lines, the loop ends.

Comment: I also added some code to check if the answer is correct and it keeps count.

Comment: Thanks for the help my friend, but your example is too advanced. I am a newbie and cannot understand alot of what you have written. Any simple method?

Comment: Copy and paste my code and run it. It's a complete running program. You don't have to do anything to it, just run it. Make sure you input the correct file name or the program with give you an error.

Comment: i am getting error on "newLine", in the Case 0, 1 and 2. Why? The error is that "newLine can not be resolved to a variable".

Comment: I changed it. all the `in.nextLine()` should be `input.nextLine()`. You need to change. I updated my code.

Comment: I edited a new copy. I checked ALL the errors. it runs fine. Copy the new version.

Comment: The program is not running good enough. The program just asks for a filname and suddenly it just chooses alot of verbs and just ends the program by saying that you got 0 right.

Comment: Think I fixed it. try it now. I just added a new Scanner. I was using same one for the file and user input. That was the problem.

Comment: Working now. What is missing now is to let the user decide how many verbs it wants to be tested in...?

Comment: Use the `for` loop like you had before. EVerything that's inside the `while` loop, just put it inside your `for` loop.

Comment: My friend what is wordIndex?

Comment: the three words are in the array `tokens`. In order to find out if the guess equals the empty word, you need to know what work is empty. In the switch, it tells you what `wordIndex` should be so when you compare with guess, you take the word from `tokens` at index `wordindex`

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I have got to figure out to fix the for loop and so on. But now I need help from you with how to get the total score from the user. After the user is finished with the amount of the verbs then the user will get a total score. Percentage 0-100%. Can you help?